# Does Convert.ToSingle() then System.Convert.ToString() cause miscalculation for Double input?

Tags: c#, math

I know title is not clear enough , let me explain. I'm working on a project about an iterative algorithm to compute geodetic coordinates and this is the first part of it. Basically program is doing some iterative calculations using the textbox inputs. It converts textbox input to Single , uses it for calculation and then converts to String as an output. At some points , I need to use an output as an input for following processes but the problem is , it gives slightly different results. For example , these are the results of an online calculator for x,y,z : 1114125.84474949 , -4844708.42056692 , 3982826.71498173 ; and these are mine 1114125.55452963 , 4844708.5526556 , 3982826.75245773. What causes this? (don't mind the missing minus of y). To sum up , i wonder if converting textbox texts to single then , converting them to string cause this error or not. I hope question is clear.

Here is a part of codes which gave the results I mentioned above. More complicated iterations will also work like this , if I can solve the issue.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start(); // it's beside the point

        double fi = Convert.ToSingle(phi.Text);
        double lamda = Convert.ToSingle(lambda.Text);//lamda is input, lambda is textbox
        double yuk = Convert.ToSingle(height.Text);
        double a = Convert.ToSingle(aa.Text);
        double b = Convert.ToSingle(bb.Text);
        double ec = (Math.Pow(a, 2) - Math.Pow(b, 2)) / Math.Pow(a, 2); //eccentricity
        double N = a / Math.Sqrt(1 - ec * Math.Pow(Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * fi), 2));

        double xx = ((N + yuk) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * fi) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * lamda));

        double yy = ((N + yuk) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * fi) * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * lamda));

        double zz = ((Math.Pow(b/a,2) * N + yuk) * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * fi));

        coorx.Text = System.Convert.ToString(xx); //xx, yy, zz are textboxes

        coory.Text = System.Convert.ToString(yy);

        coorz.Text = System.Convert.ToString(zz);
    }
```

Comment: Doing *anything* with a binary floating point number allows room for error. So, the short answer to your question in your title is, yes. More to the point, though, there's probably a lot you could improve about this, but the first thing I notice is that you're storing your data as `double`, but using `Convert.ToSingle()`. Why are you converting to a 32 bit number and storing it as a 64 bit number?

Comment: Can you also add the input values for which you got these results? All calculations are done on `double`s, but the input is first converted to `float` - that might cause unnecessary loss of precision.

Comment: As @GlorinOakenfoot and @JakubLortz say, it is very strange to convert `ToSingle` (single-precision, `float`) when your variables are `double` (double-precision). Why do you do that?!

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Well , even if I use float instead of double , it doesnt work for the ones with functions. Ex: 

    double xx = ((N + yuk) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * fi) * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * lamda));

What type of value shall I use instead of double or what value type shall  i convert to?

Comment: @JakubLortz I understand my mistake but , please teach me , what type of value shall I pick to get rid of this issue? Which one should be altered , double or single? Regards  .

Comment: @HasanKaraman The point is that `Convert.ToSingle()` converts to a *float*, which is a 32 bit number, and is less accurate. You are *storing*, and *working* with the numbers as 64 bit numbers, however. It would be sensible to use `Convert.ToDouble()`, which would treat the numbers from the textboxes as 64 bit numbers, and at the very least, you could rule that out as a source of inaccuracy.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot thanks sir , I got this.

Answer (score -1):

Computer use binary format in order to store numbers in the memory, in additon there is limited number of bits that are used to store these values (depend on the type which use), therefore conversion of the string value, which is given in decimal number format, and is of single / double  type (so real value number) is usally related with degradation of precision.